# Enabling DOTNET COM extension in PHP 5.6.12

Tags: php, .net, com, php-extension

In a PHP project I need to use the [DOTNET COM library](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php), but I saw it is disabled.
I don't know how to enable it, so I tried uncommenting the following lines in my `php.ini` file, under the [com] section:

```
com.typelib_file = php_com_dotnet.dll 
com.allow_dcom = true
pextension=php_com_dotnet.dll 
com.autoregister_typelib = true
com.autoregister_casesensitive = false
com.autoregister_verbose = true
com.code_page=
```

I am still gettting errors saying `Class 'COM' not found`.
Any suggestions on what to do?
Thanks.

Comment: Might want to fix `pextension` first...

Comment: You need to check the modules part are you using windows or sx or linux? make sure extension=php_com_dotnet.dll doesn't have an ; in front of it in php.ini. Another way to debug what's enabled it create a php page and add echo phpinfo(); to it and see the result

Comment: hi guys! thanks so much will try our your advices. thanks much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First check this in php.ini

```
[PHP_COM_DOTNET]
extension=php_com_dotnet.dll
```

after it chek where you said php to look for extension , and to enable extention.
you must remove ";" from first of this line :

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

and enable extension with this flag

```
enable_dl = On
```

it must solve your problem.

Comment: Please explain that enable_dl = On
 where should be defined in php.ini?